# Broken tests comparing 2 objects with a map inside JUnit 4.12

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I've updated my JUnit version from 4.10 to 4.12 and after doing that, some tests have broken.

These tests compare 2 objects with a map inside, the 2 objects are identical, but I get the following error when asserting on them like so:

```
assertThat(event, equalTo(expectedEvent));
```

The error is the following:

```
Expected: <Event(prop1=value1, prop2=value2...propertyN={key=value})>
 but: was <Event(prop1=value1, prop2=value2...propertyN={ "key" : "value"})>
```

As you can see the issue is the way JUnit interprets the map, expecting **key=value**, but it was **"key" : "value"**.

In JUnit < 4.12, the difference between the expected and the actual value is still there, but it's more benevolent and the tests pass, but not in JUnit 4.12.

How do I fix this? how do I make JUnit parse the map the same way in the expected object and the actual object?

Edit: the problem has been nailed to how JUnit expects the map, as it expects it in **{key=value}** style regardless of how the property is parsed.

Thank you
Greetings

Comment: Do you have an `equals()` method inside `Event.class` to test for proper equality?

Comment: You're right, I don't. The standard toString() method returns the map in { "key" : "value"} style. I'll try implementing it

Comment: The problem remains as it still expect the property as **{key=value}**

Comment: It looks like either `Event.equals` doesn't do a deep equality check, or that the `Map.equals` isn't implemented (correctly)

Comment: right, event.equals(expectedEvent) returns false... but why you think this is? I haven't implemented the equals method in the Event class

Answer (score 0):

I have finally identified the issue. The problem was that the Event objects were being filled with 2 different HashMap implementations, and their toString() implementations were different, one generated **{key=value}** whilst the other one returned **{"key" : "value"}**, therefore creating discrepancies.

Instead of messing with the equals method in the Event class, what I have done is parsing both Events to JSON before `assertingThat` them. This way both HashMaps are parsed the same way :-)

Thanks you guys!